# Find swing component using ComponentFinder

Tags: java, swing, testing

I have a code (swing):

```
javax.swing.JButton loginbutton = new javax.swing.JButton("Login");
loginbutton.setName("LoginButton126");
```

and test for it:

```
ComponentFinder finder = BasicComponentFinder.finderWithCurrentAwtHierarchy();
javax.swing.JButton loginbutton = (javax.swing.JButton) finder.findByName("LoginButton126");
```

but unfortunatelly I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fest/util/Strings
```

What should I change ?

Best regards

Comment: This expection has nothing to do with swing, also not the code you added throws it. The fest-assert library is missing from your classpath.

Comment: Are you sure, because I try also another method: in test code I create identical object and try find equal object. Like this:  javax.swing.JButton loginbutton2 = new javax.swing.JButton("Login");
loginbutton2.setName("LoginButton126");
 
System.out.println(finder.equals(loginbutton2));

but return value is false (without any exception)

Comment: @DDD try this http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-lookup.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work fine

By creating a new ComponentFinder that only has access to the GUI components created after it. In the following example, finder has access to MainFrame but not to LoginFrame.

```
// new LoginFrame();
ComponentFinder finder = BasicComponentFinder.finderWithNewAwtHierarchy();
finder.findByName("login", true); // will fail finding component of login frame
// new MainFrame();
finder.findByName("pw", true); // will work finding label of main frame
```

Comment: Doesn't work too, I have:
Exception in thread "main" org.fest.swing.exception.ComponentLookupException: Unable to find component using matcher org.fest.swing.core.NameMatcher[name='LoginButton126', type=java.awt.Component, requireShowing=false].

I also add  .setVisible but still the same effect
$155=new javax.swing.JButton("Login");
 $155.setName("LoginButton126");
 $155.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to make all of the component variables be class variables so that you can access them anywhere. However, not everyone wants to do that, and some (like myself) are using GUI Editors that don't generate the components as class variables.

My solution is simple, I'd like to think, and doesn't really violate any programming standards, as far as I know (referencing what fortran was getting at). It allows for an easy and straightforward way to access components by name.

Create a Map class variable. You'll need to import HashMap at the very least. I named mine componentMap for simplicity.

```
private HashMap componentMap;
```

Add all of your components to the frame as normal.

```
initialize() {
    //add your components and be sure
    //to name them.
    ...
    //after adding all the components,
    //call this method we're about to create.
    createComponentMap();
}
```

> Define the following two methods in your class. You'll need to import

Component if you haven't already:

```
private void createComponentMap() {
        componentMap = new HashMap<String,Component>();
        Component[] components = yourForm.getContentPane().getComponents();
        for (int i=0; i < components.length; i++) {
                componentMap.put(components[i].getName(), components[i]);
        }
}

public Component getComponentByName(String name) {
        if (componentMap.containsKey(name)) {
                return (Component) componentMap.get(name);
        }
        else return null;
}
```

Now you've got a HashMap that maps all the currently existing components in your frame/content pane/panel/etc to their respective names.

To now access these components, it is as simple as a call to getComponentByName(String name). If a component with that name exists, it will return that component. If not, it returns null. It is your responsibility to cast the component to the proper type. I suggest using instanceof to be sure.

If you plan on adding, removing, or renaming components at any point during runtime, I would consider adding methods that modify the HashMap according to your changes.

Comment: I saw that code but my problem is that I have a project in c++ and in that code there is generated code in java swing and that generated code is invoked. So it could be difficult to use such a map (because I don't have .java files to include in my tests). Regarding to this I thought that I will be able to add line .setName .setVisible and after that I will be also able to find such component in my test using ComponentFinder. But I was wrong it doesn't work in that way.